# Texmaker will not compile unless opened through terminal

Tags: latex

I have the problem that Texmaker 4.4.1 does not compiled if it is started from the icon in the appications menu, but it does compile if started from the terminal. When I do the quick build, the program shows no errors, it is just that it doesnt seem to do anything appart from showing the generic output in the log window. Or put differently: Texmaker starts if it is opened from the command line and/or from the applications menu, but will not compile TeX unless started from the command line.

I am on Debian Strech. This happened whilst I was on Wheezy too, but back then I gave up to try to find the problem. It seemed too difficult.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you mean that Texmaker doesn't start except from the command line,
or that it starts either way, but then will not properly compile TeX
unless started from the command line?

Comment: @dhag, thanks for the comment. I responded to the comment by adding information which addresses your question in the above the description.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Texmaker, but foes it have a mode where it can show the commands it is executing when attempting to compile? Presumably the environments differ between the command line and the window manager methods, and this would help finding out what exactly is the matter. If you can, then please add any error messages to your question.

Comment: @dhag I hope this is not a silly question, but how do I find out if such a mode exist? I tried to make a few searches on google in layman terms, but didnt find anything useful. Does such modes have a specific name which I can use when I try to find out if Texmaker has such a mode? Thanks